# A problem in this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

There is an exercise where we have a system of two equations,we need to find B and C, its this:
Equation 1: $$\sqrt{2}-3=\left[\sqrt{2}B+C\right]\left[\sqrt{2}+4\right]$$
Equation 2: $$-\sqrt{2}-3=\left[-\sqrt{2}B+C\right]\left[-\sqrt{2}+4\right]$$
After some calculation I got to $$1-4B-C=-1+4B+C$$
But this is impossible as it shows that $$-1=1$$

Comment: No, that shows that $(1 - 4B - C) = -(1 - 4B - C)$, implying that $1 - 4B - C = 0$.

Comment: Oh yes i got it, dividing by 0 has no meaning so i cant divide by (1-4B-C), thanks. :)

Comment: You don't need to write $\sqrt(2)$; you can write $\sqrt{2}$. See my edits to your question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you michael, just a starter here btw